# How to compare the values for multiple rows in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a Source table as shown below..

```
Name    Subject Marks   Year

A   Science 88  2015
A   Social  75  2015
A   Social  75  2015
A   Maths   22  2015
B   Social  75  2015
B   Maths   50  2014
C   Science 88  2015
C   Social  75  2014
D   Science 88  2015
D   Social  75  2015
A   Social  75  2015
B   Maths   50  2014
```

and I have a requirement as below like if any student has satisfies both as in below requirements then he should be awarded as respected requirement set name in the another table B

```
Set1

Social  75  2015
Science 88  2015

Set2

Social  75  2015
Maths   50  2014
```

The expected output in the table B is as below

```
Name    Status
A   Set1
B   Set2
C   None
D   Set1
```

Comment: Please review the answers given below (they both work...up to you to choose one).

Comment: I have changed the Requirement Could you please check the changes and help me on That

Comment: How do you want to handle the case where someone matches _both_ Set1 and Set2?

Comment: Then we will go with the first case as, we come from first case if case1 satisfies then we will come out for that name

Comment: I updated my answer ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
SELECT NAME,
       CASE WHEN SUM(SCIENCE) + SUM(SOCIAL) = 2 THEN 'GOOD' ELSE 'BAD' END AS Status
  FROM (SELECT NAME,
               CASE
                  WHEN SUBJECT = 'Science' AND MARKS = 88 AND YEAR = 2015
                  THEN 1 ELSE 0
               END
                  AS SCIENCE,
               CASE
                  WHEN SUBJECT = 'Social' AND MARKS = 75 AND YEAR = 2015
                  THEN  1 ELSE 0
               END
                  AS SOCIAL
          FROM A) group by Name;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/abf5a/3)

[image]

[EDIT] if you have some rules to add, add a case in subquery, and update the top case :

```
    SELECT NAME,
       CASE WHEN MAX(SCIENCE) + MAX(SOCIAL) = 2 THEN 'Set1' 
       WHEN MAX(SOCIAL) + MAX(MATHS) =2 THEN 'Set2'
       ELSE 'None'END AS Status
  FROM (SELECT NAME,
               CASE
                  WHEN SUBJECT = 'Science' AND MARKS = 88 AND YEAR = 2015
                  THEN 1 ELSE 0
               END
                  AS SCIENCE,
               CASE
                  WHEN SUBJECT = 'Social' AND MARKS = 75 AND YEAR = 2015
                  THEN  1 ELSE 0
               END
                  AS SOCIAL,
              CASE
                  WHEN SUBJECT = 'Maths' AND MARKS = 50 AND YEAR = 2014
                  THEN  1 ELSE 0
               END AS MATHS
          FROM A)x group by Name;
```

See the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2f17/4)

[image]

Comment: I can't get SQL Fiddle to work.  Could you test my query?

Comment: SqlFiddle is broken right now... @Raj if one of the answer is good for you, please validate :-)

Comment: Sql fiddleis now working, see the second SQL Fiddle link

Comment: The OP has mentioned possible duplicates in the data *(comment on another answer, and in the current example data)*, and I'd imagine that these duplicates may not always even be identical *(potentially different scores for the same subject in the same year?)*.  As such I'd recommend `MAX(science)`, `MAX(social)`, etc, rather than `SUM(science)`, etc *(So that **two science passes** don't count the same as **one science pass and one social pass**, for example)*.

Comment: @Raj can you explain why you validated and un-validated my anwser please?

Comment: Can he explain why he changed the original question twice after we both already had functioning answers?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - That's the nature of the beast; if the OP could clearly state the problem in an single attempt then they would be much more likely to have been able to solve it themselves.  Low score + needing to ask + lack of detail = risk of changing requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT t2.Name AS Name, CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN t2.Status = 'Set1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 2 THEN 'Set1'
    WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN t2.Status = 'Set2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 2 THEN 'Set2'
    ELSE 'None' END AS Status
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        CASE WHEN (t.Subject = 'Social' AND t.Marks >= 75 AND t.Year = '2015') THEN 'Set1'
            WHEN (t.Subject = 'Science' AND t.Marks >= 88 AND t.Year = '2015') THEN 'Set1'
            WHEN (t.Subject = 'Social' AND t.Marks >= 75 AND t.Year = '2015') THEN 'Set2'
            WHEN (t.Subject = 'Maths' AND t.Marks >= 50 AND t.Year = '2014') THEN 'Set2'
            ELSE 'None' END AS Status,
        t.Name, t.Subject, t.Marks, t.Year
    FROM A t
) t2
GROUP BY t2.Name
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed393)**

**Output:**

```
+------+--------+
| Name | Status |
+------+--------+
|  A   | Set1   |
|  B   | Set2   |
|  C   | None   |
|  D   | Set1   |
+------+--------+
```

Comment: I have changed the Requirement Could you please check the changes and help me on That

Comment: What if the Name A has duplicate value like A  Social  75  2015 twice

Comment: I updated my query to use `SELECT DISTINCT` in the inner query.  Please mark as correct if it solved your problem, thanks.

Comment: @Raj - Is it possible for two records to have the same `Name, Subject, Year` but have different `Marks`?  Like someone resitting an exam?  If so, does the more recent mark count, or does the highest mark count?  *(If it is possible, the current answer doesn't cope with it.)*

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Nope, I think the use of `SUM()` and `DISTINCT` is weaker than using `MAX()` for a variety of reasons, but it works given the current description.

Comment: There is a potentially bigger problem other than what you pointed out: A given name may fall into _multiple_ set categories.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - The OP said that if the Name passes both `Set1` and `Set2` then `Set1` has precedence.  *(Which I thought your answer catered for.)*  Which your answer does indeed only half-cater for.  I think this should not be the accepted answer, in its current form.

Comment: No...my answer _fully_ caters for this.  It also caters birthday parties and bar mitzvahs for those who are interested.

Comment: Why so aggressive?  And are you sure your query caters for that scenario?  I took your current answer, fixed the typos *(Missing `END`s from `CASE` statements, illegally placed `DISTINCT`, wrong alias used at `A.Marks` - should be `t.Marks`)* and then actually tested it; Check the result for `Name = 'B'`...   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/abf5a/10  *(Now I have down-voted, but am very happy to up-vote as and when it is corrected.*)